# Numpy Python: Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, regression, linear-regression

Getting exception  `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`

using NumPy in Python 3.7

Same code is working for others but not in my case. Bellow is my code please help

> [Working_code_in_diff_system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XBq8.jpg)
>
> [Same_code_not_working_in_my_system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw3r6.jpg)

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('./Data/new-data.csv', index_col=False)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['Hours'], df['Marks'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

sns.jointplot(x=df['Hours'], y=df['Marks'], data=df, kind='reg')

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1,1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1,1))
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (-1,1))
y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (-1,1))



#
print('Train - Predictors shape', x_train.shape)
print('Test - Predictors shape', x_test.shape)
print('Train - Target shape', y_train.shape)
print('Test - Target shape', y_test.shape)
```

Expected output should be

> Train - Predictors shape (80, 1)
>
> Test - Predictors shape (20, 1)
>
> Train - Target shape (80, 1)
>
> Test - Target shape (20, 1)

As output getting exception `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`

Comment: Your first `jpg` hints at the problem, `reshape` on a Series will be deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to call `np.reshape` on the underlying numpy array rather than on the Pandas series - you can do this using `.values`:

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train.values, (-1, 1))
```

Repeat the same idea for the next three lines.

Or,  if you are on a recent version of Pandas >= 0.24, `to_numpy` is preferred:

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train.to_numpy(), (-1, 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

`numpy.squeeze()` removes all dimensions of size 1 from a NumPy array.

```
x_train = numpy.squeeze(x_train)
```

Converts a (80,1) array to (80,)